# translate dataframe with dictionary in python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Having the following `pandas Dataframe` sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[1,2],[3,5]])

df
    0   1
0   1   2
1   1   2
2   3   5
```

And the following dictionary:

```
d = {1:'foo',2:'bar',3:'tar',4:'tartar',5:'foofoo'}
```

I would like to "translate" the dataframe by using the dictionary `d`. **The output** looks like:

```
result = pd.DataFrame([['foo','bar'],['foo','bar'],['tar','fofo']])

result
    0   1
0   foo bar
1   foo bar
2   tar fofo
```

I would like to avoid using for loops. The solution I'm trying to find is something with map or similars...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Solution

- Replacing whole dataframe:

  ```
  result_1 = df.replace(d)
  ```
- Replacing a specific column of a dataframe:

  ```
  result_2 = df.replace({"COLUMN":d})
  ```

Comment: what about translating only one column?

Comment: df.replace({"COLUMN":d})  :)